# Adapter: 1/8" Dremel shank to 1/4" chuck

Tags: adapter, chuck

**Situation**: I have a Dremel rotary tool with normal 1/8" shank and a Dremel Multi-Vice.

**Need**: I wish to attach this Dremel tool (with standard 1/8" shank held stead with my  Dremel Multi-Vice) for cleaning with a larger-diameter wire-brush that is normally available with 1/4" shank.

**Question**: Is there an adapter that has a 1/8" shank with a 1/4" chuck?

Comment: Although you may find some sort of aftermarket adapter, it is important to remember that the collet is sized for bits/accessories that can be safely driven by the tool's motor. Upsizing to a larger shank size accessory is deliberately discouraged via collet size, and doing so could exceed the capability of the Dremel. You should use a wire brush with the 1/8" shank.

Comment: You are absolutely correct and 100% on the money; I got this silly idea since I had a 1) 1/4" mandrel wire brush (that can be used with a normal drill) and 2) Dremel rotor and a Dremel vice/rotor clamp.  I was simply toying with the idea of finding an adapter that would let me use the best of both tools. When I was at Mendards, I found a relatively inexpensive regular vice-clamp for about $15.  Guess, this investment is better than breaking the 1/8" collect and injuring myself

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even if someone makes an adapter in this direction, it's a **Very Bad Idea.**

1/4 down to 1/8 - no problem. 1/8 up to 1/4 - big problems.

You may exceed the speed rating of the larger shank tool - small shank tools tend to spin a lot faster, and can do so because their tools are smaller. Spin a tool that's too large too fast and you can explode it by centrifugal force. Shrapnel in all directions. Messy and frequently causing injuries.

Big to small does not need to extend the tool shaft. Small to big does, and that extension is inherently unstable. You're overloading the bearings both by putting on a tool that is bigger and heavier AND by giving it more leverage - this is bad for the bearings. You can actually bend the shaft, and once bent, it will bend more and flail about, also likely causing injuries.

Comment: Totally agree. you would also shorten the life of the motor.

Comment: Thank you Ecnerwal, JImmy and Jack.  I had thought about the point you made (exceed rating) in the passing but nevertheless thought about asking as I read somewhere on the internet that Dremel did make a similar-functional adapter in the past.  However, you are 100% correct from a theoretical and practical perspective.  So, I will ditch the idea. Thanks for your, quick, PERFECT, and WELL REASONED explanation. I am closing this thread. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 4):

### The Dremel won't have the power to drive that wire wheel

Wire wheels take a lot more power to drive than you think.  That 2" or 3" wire wheel is made for a drill capable of driving a 3/8" bit into hardwood or a 1/4” bit into steel.  It is simply going to stall the Dremel the first time it touches work.

At first I thought "too fast", but then I realized the cup brushes I use on my grinder are rated for 14,000 RPM, which is faster than my Dremel.

Comment: ...but many "drill" brushes are only rated to 3,000 or 5,000 Grinder brushes are built to go fast because they are designed to be used on a tool that goes fast. The combination of a grinder and brush designed for use on a grinder is a good way to get work done, of course.

Comment: The Dremel will have plenty of power to drive that wheel to the extent that something gets damaged. Also there's enough people critical of the quality of Dremel's choice of bearings even when used with normal accessories that I think their concerns should be noted. If OP needs power, he should get a half-decent drill (plus gloves and face protection). If he needs compact power, he should get himself a decent die grinder (plus gloves and face protection).

Comment: Thanks Harper, Ecnerwal & Mark.  Based on all you value-added input and  some practical common-sense (on my part) of not pushing adapters too much, I bought myself another hand mini-vice-and-drill-clamp that can take hold standard 120V power-drills.

Answer (score 1):

Dremel make a [range of wire brushes](https://www.dremel.com/en_US/accessories-and-attachments/-/subcategory/accessory/find-by-tool/27343/rotary/27386) that fit the Dremel Rotary Tool - why not just use that instead?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and link.  Yesterday I was at Menards and bought a couple of abrasive wheels as part of a set for $19.  Thought that paying a little more and getting a lot of other accessories was better than spending ~$6 on just one of them.  Have put it to use and it works jut perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, for your extremely dangerous project..

https://www.etsy.com/listing/912183557/14-inch-mega-chuck-for-dremel-extra?variation0=1670937965

1/4 inch Mega Chuck for Dremel (Extra Large quarter inch chuck for rotary tools)

Comment: this is borderline spam/link only. Please take the [tour] to see how things work around here.